# Как сравнить два типа ? С++

Tags: c++, qt, типы

Мне надо сравнить два типа. Как это сделать ?
Допустим я беру из базы типы колонок. И вывожу если это строка `String`, если целое `int`:

```
if (fieldTable.type() == QString) {
   qDebug()<<"String";
} else if (fieldTable.type() == int) {
 qDebug()<<"int";
}
```

Comment: Какой тип у `fieldTable` и `type()`?

Comment: @gil9red QVariant::int
QVariant::QString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если `fieldTable` это [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), тогда [.type()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#type) возвращает [перечисление](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant-obsolete.html#Type-enum).

Если в `fieldTable` хранится `QString`, тогда `type()` будет `QVariant::String`, а `int` – `QVariant::Int`

Comment: А забыл подключить #include <QVariant> , а так if (fieldTable.type()== QVariant::String)